# The existence of a specific maximal ideal in a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

I'm reviewing past questions on the algebra prelim at my university, and I came across this question.

"Let $R$ be a UFD and I a proper principal ideal. Prove that $R$ has a proper principal ideal that is maximal with respect to the property of containing I and identify its generator interms of the generator of $I$."
This is what I have so far:

Let $I=(x)$. In a UFD, we have the unique decomposition into irreducibles/primes. so
$$x=p_1p_2\dots p_n$$
This implies that $I\subset (p_i)$ for $1\leq i \leq n$. Now I must show that all (or just one?) of these prime ideals are maximal. If $R$ was also PID, then prime ideals are maximal, but this is not the case with UFDs in general. I don't know how to show if $(p_i)$ is contained in some ideal $M$, then either $(p_i)=M$ or $M=R$ given that $M$ may not be principal.

Comment: Look at the collection of all proper principal ideals of R which contain I. This is for sure non-empty because it contains I. The only thing you need to show is that it has a maximal element. The trick is to use the Zorn’s Lemma.

Comment: I don't think the ideal you find is supposed to be a maximal ideal, but rather *maximal among proper principal ideals containing $I$*. The phrasing of the question is unclear, though. And I think you can show that $(p_i)$ satisfies that for any $i$.